# sum sql rows and add to a new column

Tags: sql

say i have this result to this query..

```
customername      p8    p12   p750   p1   m8
customer1         5     48     4     4    4
customer2         4            2     5    43
customer3         4     -3
```

now i want to ask if is there a way that i could add all the rows to form something like this:

```
customername      p8    p12   p750   p1   m8     total
customer1         5     48     4     4    4       65
customer2         4            2     5    43      54
customer3         4     -3                        1
```

can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Have you even tried solving it on your own? `UPDATE TableName SET total = p8 + p12 + p750 + p1 + m8`, or to just select that stuff: `SELECT *, p8+p12+p750+p1+m8 as total FROM TableName`.

Comment: hmm no.. since total field is not yet added to the query...i have tried to add the rows yet i only got one result for total. i only got successful result to row 1 and the succeeding row for total got null value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table tbl1 (m1 int, m2 int);

insert into tbl1 (m1,m2) values 
(25,50),(30,43);
```

**Query:**

```
select m1,m2, (m1+m2) as total from tbl1;
```

## [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/348b2/1)

Answer (score 4):

Sum up the fields and use an alias to name the dynamic column in your select

```
select coalesce(p8,0)+
       coalesce(p12,0)+
       coalesce(p750,0)+
       coalesce(p1,0)+
       coalesce(m8,0) as total
from your_table
```

If some of your column allow `null` then you have to use a function like `coalesce` to replace that with `0` since `1+null=null`.

Comment: yeah i tried that but i only got one result for total field

Comment: yeahh man...your the man...thanks..it works now..i bow down..yey

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customername,   p8, p12 , p750, p1, m8, 
 COALESCE (p8,0) + COALESCE (p12,0) + COALESCE (p750,0) +     COALESCE (p1,0) + COALESCE (m8,0) AS total
FROM table
```